# Receiving dbus signals with pythion

Tags: python, dbus, dbus-python

I'm trying to write some python to listen to signals.

Using dbus-monitor, as shown below, I can filter the signals I want.

```
dbus-monitor "type='signal',sender='org.kde.KWin',path='/ColorCorrect',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',member='PropertiesChanged'"

signal time=1653997355.732016 sender=:1.4 -> destination=(null destination) serial=13165 path=/ColorCorrect; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.kde.kwin.ColorCorrect"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "enabled"
         variant             boolean false
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

But when I try the same thing with python, see below, nothing gets printed.

```
import dbus
from gi.repository import GLib
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop


def signal_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    for i, arg in enumerate(args):
        print("arg:%d        %s" % (i, str(arg)))
    print('kwargs:')
    print(kwargs)
    print('---end----')


DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus()

# register your signal callback
bus.add_signal_receiver(signal_handler,
                        bus_name='org.kde.KWin',
                        interface_keyword='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',
                        member_keyword='PropertiesChanged',
                        path_keyword='/ColorCorrect'
                        # message_keyword='msg')
                        )

loop = GLib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in: [NightColor.py for Setting Temp From Terminal](https://zren.github.io/2020/05/14/nightcolorpy-for-setting-temp-from-terminal) which explains using `pydbus` to communicate the *Night Color effect* done by KWin using codename “ColorCorrect”.

### Solution

See the docs of [pydbus, Connecting to the Bus](https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus/blob/master/doc/tutorial.rst#connecting-to-the-bus):

> There are generally two bus daemons you may be interested in. Each **user login *session*** should have a ***session* bus**, which is local to that session. It's used to communicate between desktop applications. Connect to the session bus by creating a `SessionBus` object:

```
from pydbus import SessionBus

session_bus = SessionBus()
```

### Session bus in KDE

#### Default: *session* bus

From the [`dbus-monitor` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-monitor):

> Options
> `--system`   Monitor the system message bus.
> `--session`  Monitor the **session message bus**. (This is the **default**.)

So, the message you saw in the output was apparently form default session-bus.

Same default bus explained in KDE's Developer guide: [Accessing D-Bus Interfaces](https://develop.kde.org/docs/use/d-bus/accessing_dbus_interfaces/):

> A `QDBusInterface` object represents a given D-Bus interface. The constructor accepts as parameters (in order) a service name, an object path, an optional interface and optionally which bus (e.g. *system* or *session*) to use. If no bus is explicitly defined, it **defaults to the *session* bus**. If no interface is given, the returned object will be used to call all interfaces on the bus.

#### Note

The given DBus-Service name for KDE's Plasma Desktop window manager [*KWin*](https://userbase.kde.org/KWin) (`org.kde.KWin`) can also have a suffix, see environment-variable [`KWIN_DBUS_SERVICE_SUFFIX`](https://community.kde.org/KWin/Environment_Variables#KWIN_DBUS_SERVICE_SUFFIX)

> Suffix for the DBus-Service name `"org.kde.KWin"`. If set, the name will be changed to `"org.kde.KWin.${KWIN_DBUS_SERVICE_SUFFIX}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your are using the system bus. `org.kde.KWin` is a service of the session bus. Try:

```py
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
```

Comment: Can we conclude: Given Color Correction is controlled by the window manager (KWin) when user is logged in to a session. Thus the related message is sent over the session-bus (as usually for session-related components, services or applications like KWin) ?